# Use an Asus Transformer Tablet with Cisco VPN Connections

Tags: vpn, android, cisco-anyconnect

Our company has recently bought an Asus Transformer Tablet, running Android 3 (Honeycomb). I have been tinkering around with it for a while now and have so far failed badly to get this tablet to connect to our company's VPN.

We are using a set of ASA 5520 filewalls using the latest Cisco OS Versions, however nothing I seem to do will allow the tablet to connect to them.

I Noticed that Cisco has an [AnyConnect client](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android) available on the Android Market, however this only works on Samsung Phones / Tablets. (I did try installing it).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this tablet to connect to our VPN or a an Android application that would be able to cure this problem?

Comment: There's an [AnyConnect for rooted devices](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.rooted). Any chance you can root the Asus?

Comment: Unfortunatly not, whilst i have nothing against rooting the device if it was for my own use, due to it being for our company i need to ensure it stays as secure and safe as possible, so rooting is out of the question :(